# Calling JavaScript code using AJAX (In PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**test2.php (Temporary name):**

```
    <?php 
if ($_SESSION["dbrows_now"] > $_SESSION["dbrows_prev"]) {
echo "<p>Previous Rows</p>";
echo $_SESSION["dbrows_prev"];
echo "<p>Now</p>";
echo $_SESSION["dbrows_now"];
echo "<h3>The rows have changed as you can see</h3>";
//$_SESSION["dbrows_prev"] = $_SESSION["dbrows_now"];
echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('chat');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 1);
</script>
";
}
?>
```

JavaScript to call the code using AJAX/JavaScript:

```
//Function that updates new rows
function newrows(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {

            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/test2.php?success=true"+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

//Updates new rows every x seconds
setInterval('newrows()',5000);
```

Basically I am working on a really simple chat system where I am counting the number of rows using PHP and if they change then the div will scroll to the bottom of the page.

The problem is that I have the div on the index.php page, and the code is on the example.php page.

For some reason if I check the source of my code I can see that the JavaScript code has been echoed to the index.php page **(But the code doesn't work, but if I paste it into my index page directly it does work)**

Notes:
I can't put the code directly into the index page because I only want it to perform the code when a new message has been added (Well a new row) (It just keeps scrolling to the bottom 24/7 of course if I did)

*And I know about WebSockets so please don't keep telling me how bad this system is!*

***THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!***

Side Note: I am very good with PHP but know very little JavaScript, this is why my code for making a system like this is so bad...

Edit: I just wanted to let everyone know I am open to any other Jquery or JavaScript solutions to getting the PHP code to execute, thank you!

Comment: You've tagged your question with [tag:jquery], but you are using raw `XMLHttpRequest`s. Maybe, you should look into [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I did this because I am also open to any solutions to my problem that have been done in jQuery!

Thanks.

Comment: the first problem that stands out to me is `setInterval('newrows()',5000);`, your sending setInterval a string, it needs to be a function. eg. `setInterval(newrows,5000);` or `setInterval(function(){newrows('some string')},5000);`.

Comment: @2pha Thank you for that sir, although it wasn't causing any issues, but thank you very much.

My problem is that I cannot execute this javascript from an XMLHTTP request, and I really need to.

Thanks